# Change the window-terminal to Emacs edit-mode

Tags: windows-10, terminal, powershell, emacs

I plan to change the window-terminal to Emacs-Editing style with:

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -EditMode Emacs
```

but it failed to work when start new terminal instance or restart the machine.

As a solution, I write `Set-PSReadLineOption -EditMode Emacs` to startup.ps1  within `/c/Users/gaowei/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Startup`

Unfortunately, it still does not work after restart machine.

What's the problem? How could change terminal's edit mode to emacs permanently？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. Files in the *Startup* folder in Start menu is for executing something at startup and has nothing to do with PowerShell. You need to modify your [PowerShell profile](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-profile.html) to make it apply to each PowerShell session. Just run the below command

```
Add-Content -Path $PROFILE -Value 'Set-PSReadLineOption -EditMode Emacs'
```

to add the required command to the profile. After that reopen PowerShell or run `. $PROFILE` to [source](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-constrained-language-mode-and-the-dot-source-operator/) the profile to [apply the new setting immediately](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts?view=powershell-7#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing)

You an also edit the profile by running `notepad.exe $PROFILE` or by opening it with any text editor you prefer

For more information read [About Profiles](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7)